# If/else statement contingent upon existence of xpath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm unclear on how to check for the existence of a particular xpath in an if/else statement (I'm also unsure if using xpaths is the best method).

I essentially want to do the following (with a list of URLs that link to search results which may or may not exist/be complete):

For each URL:

1. check if the appropriate search result page exists
2. if it exists, check if a 'More Info' button exists
3. if it exists, check if each data field exists/is populated
4. for all empty fields/sections/pages, fill in dictionary with blanks

I've tried doing this by defining a function to check for the existence of an xpath, and using it in nested if/else statements, but these are returning errors.

Current code is as follows:

Function to check for existence of xpath (boolean):

```
def hasxpath(xpath):
    try: 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Code to work through list of URLs:

```
for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/xxx')
    driver.get(url)

    # Check if search result page exists
    if hasxpath('xxx') == True:

        # If 'More Info' button exists, click it
        if hasxpath('xxx') == True:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx').click()

            # For each field, check if it exists and if so collect data
            # (example below for 'Name' field)
            if hasxpath('xxx') == True:
                name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx')
                name = name.text
            else:
                name = ''
            driver.close()

        else:
            driver.close()

    else:
        driver.close()
```

This still does not appear to work when the page does not exist (it throws an error instead of executing driver.close(). Is there an easy fix for this? Or perhaps even a better way to go about checking this information and locating data (rather than using xpaths)?

Comment: What *"check if the appropriate search result page exists"* means?

Comment: @JaSON unfortunately I maxed out my access rights, but basically each URL links to a database search, and if the result exists, it sends me to the search result page, but if it does not exist, it sends me to a default page does not exist page.

Comment: "even a better way to go about checking this information and locating data (rather than using xpaths)" it doesn't matter are you using xpath, css, id or names as long as the locator is properly constructed - finds the correct element. This is like saying "perhaps it would be better to use java, javascript or go than using python" - it's just a tool. What is the actual exception, and at which line is it thrown? In your code sample here, `hasxpath()` is always called with 'xxx', but I _guess_ it is 'xxx', then 'yyy' and finally 'zzz'? If so, change the sample - or even add your actual locators.

Comment: post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine.I have checked that and absence of Xpath it is closing browser.Please run my code and do necessary changes of your url and xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def hasxpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        return True
    except:
        return False

url_list = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://www.w3schools.com/","https://www.toolsqa.com/"]

for url in url_list:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Java/TestChrome/lib/chromedriver.exe')
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    if hasxpath('xxx') == True:

        if hasxpath('xxx') == True:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx').click()

            # For each field, check if it exists and if so collect data
            # (example below for 'Name' field)
            if hasxpath('xxx') == True:
                name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx')
                name = name.text
            else:
                name = ''
            driver.close()

        else:
            driver.close()

    else:
        driver.close()
        print('Closing Browser : ' + url)

print('pass')
```